# How to store variable as nothing

Tags: c++

I have a class with `unsigned chars` inside.

There is the first instance of the class:

```
{
    unsigned char a = 5;
    unsigned char b = 243;
    unsigned char c = 0;
}
```

But there is an option some of these `unsigned chars` won't be filled.

Instance would look like this one:

```
{
    unsigned char a = 4;
    unsigned char b = 7;
    unsigned char c = <not_filled>;
}
```

I know there is the NULL defined as zero, so I cannot find out if it's zero or not_filled.

I know if I keep the variable undefined, it will be zero.

What should I do with this?

Comment: Maybe you can set it to an unused value such as 999999  or 0xffffffff

Comment: "*I know if I keep the variable undefined, it will be zero.*" - that is not guaranteed, unless the instance is created in global memory. Use `std::optional<unsigned char>` instead. [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is intended for exactly this kind of situation.

Comment: Perhaps a flag with a mask showing what vars have been filled?

Comment: Please form a complete [repro] demonstrating your problem. Most likely `std::optional` is what you want, but it is hard to tell from partial pseudo-code what you are doing.

Comment: You could use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Comment: Can someone show me a little example of code?

Comment: "Can someone show me a little example of code?" - Read the link I posted.

Answer (score 3):

[std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is what you're looking for:

```
#include <optional>

struct MyStruct {
    std::optional<unsigned char> a = 4;
    std::optional<unsigned char> b = 7;
    std::optional<unsigned char> c = std::nullopt;
};
```

An example usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

struct MyStruct {
    std::optional<unsigned char> a = std::nullopt;
    std::optional<unsigned char> b = std::nullopt;
    std::optional<unsigned char> c = std::nullopt;
};

int main() {
    MyStruct ms{'a', 'b'};
    if (ms.a.has_value()) std::cout << *ms.a << '\n';
    if (ms.b.has_value()) std::cout << *ms.b << '\n';
    if (ms.c.has_value()) std::cout << *ms.c << '\n';
}
```